# Modify DataFrame in parallel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which is fairly big (1 million rows). To keep things simple let's look at a simple DataFrame `df1` with only 5 rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      ['1', '2', '3', '4', '10'], 
                    'date':    ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                    'str':     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
```

I want to modify the `str`-column. For the sake of this example let's say that I want to apply the following function to each row of `df1`:

```
def alter_array(i):
    return (df1.str[i] + " a").upper()

for i in range(len(df1)):
    df1.str[i] = alter_array(i)
```

Is there a way to apply this function in parallel? As the individual rows are independent of each other, this would (I guess) greatly speed up the process.

---

**EDIT**: Here is an attempt at it, but this just hangs when I run the script in the terminal:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

def alter_array(df1):
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        df1.str[i] = (df1.str[i] + " a").upper()
    return df1


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':      ['1', '2', '3', '4', '10'], 
                    'date':    ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
                    'str':     ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(alter_array, df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly speed your computation by avoiding the for loops. Could you try this first?

```
df1['str'] = df1['str'].add('a').str.upper()
```

If it is still slow you could try:

```
from dask import delayed

@delayed
def alter_array(df1):
    df1['str'] = df1['str'].add('a').str.upper()
    return df1

df1 = alter_array(df1).compute()
```